# create Sharepoint Online List template from spfx app

Tags: sharepoint-online, spfx

I have to make a list template for my sharepoint online App.

I success with Element.xml and schema.xml files to create a list from a template but I need the template to be available for later use in the list template of the website.

anyone know how I can do this in my spfx app ? (I found with powershell but I have to make the template available by installing the app on the website)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on my research and testing, unfortunately there is currently no way to create a list template using SPFx. We can only create lists using SPFX. As a workaround, I still recommend you use Microsoft PowerShell to create and manage custom list templates.

**More information for reference:**

[Creating custom list templates](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/lists-custom-template)

[SharePoint List Creation Using PnP JS And SPFx](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/sharepoint-list-creation-using-pnp-js-and-spfx/)

Thanks for your understanding.

*Note: Microsoft is providing this information as a convenience to you. The sites are not controlled by Microsoft. Microsoft cannot make any representations regarding the quality, safety, or suitability of any software or information found there. Please make sure that you completely understand the risk before retrieving any suggestions from the above link.*

Comment: thanks a lot, I found the same things but I hoped to miss something.